# Does a .pfx file expire?

Tags: ssl, iis, pfx

Using IIS on Windows Server 2016.

The reason I'm asking if a .pfx file expires is because today I can no longer successfully use a certificate that I had exported yesterday.

I have a wildcard certificate that I installed on one server, and then I exported it from that server in order to import it into two other servers.  All this was done yesterday and this worked perfectly fine.

Today I want to import that same .pfx file into a fourth server but it doesn't work.  I can import it and I can bind the site to it but the browser is still showing a "this site is not secure" error.

I also made a note last year when I did the same thing that I had the same problem.  Apparently last year I was able to re-export from the first server and then import and it was fine, but this year even that doesn't work.

So my question is, why was I able to import the pfx onto two servers yesterday, but today it doesn't work?  Are pfx files only valid for the same day they were exported?

Answer (score 0):

A pfx **file** does not expire, i.e. it does not simply vanish after some time. Certificates though have an explicit life time when they are valid, i.e. a start date and an expiration date. A pfx file is a container which includes certificates, but also a private key. The private key cannot expire, the certificates do. There can be multiple certificates within the same pfx file (leaf and chain certificates) with different expiration times. Certificates can also be stored in other formats than PFX.

Comment: o.k. well then why is it I can't import a pfx that was exported just yesterday?  The certificate is good until 2023.

Comment: @Vincent: *"why is it I can't import a pfx"* - you clearly state that you can actually import it: *"__I can import it__ and I can bind the site ..."*   As for the error you get: .Unfortunately nothing is known about what exactly you did and you provide is that you get "this site is not secure" error. No more details, no way to reproduce for others. Anyway, your question about possible expiration of a pfx file is answered - a pfx file does not expire. What you face is a different problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  What I meant was, after I import it, it does not seem to be working in the browser, so perhaps the import didn't work properly.

Comment: @Vincent: I can just guess. But for example you might try to use a domain for the fourth server which is not covered by the certificate - like www.foo.example.com is not covered by a wildcard \*.example.com. The advanced information in the browser should give you more detailed information about the problems the browser has with the certificate. You should also verify that it is actually the certificate you expected.

Comment: "this site is not secure"  It more like that the server or client machine don't trust the certificate. Do the client and forth server have its root certificate and store the root certificate in trusted root certificate authorities?

Comment: @BruceZhang I'm not clear on what you're asking but to clarify, I only imported an exported version of the certificate through IIS, so I'm not sure what Windows does behind the scenes when it imports a certificate that way but I did not go through the steps that one would normally go through with a new certificate (using the console etc.).

Comment: @Vincent: Again, look at the details of the error for why it is considered insecure. Look at the certificate as shown in the browser and see if it is actually the expected one.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it is the right certificate the browser is showing.  It's showing an expiry date in 2023 so that's definitely the new certificate, but the browser is also telling me "The certificate for this site is not valid."

Comment: @Vincent: Again, you need to provide a more detailed error description than that. Please include the full error description, look for any "Advanced" information for more etc.